# MathJax not rendering column lines in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, mathjax

I'm running MathJax on the server side with Node, because I need to render math expressions into SVGs. However, a feature I really need, column lines in arrays - useful for augmented matrices - don't render correctly when converting to SVG, even though they do when directly rendering to HTML.

Here's a minimal example:

```js
import fs from "fs";

const MathJax = await (await import("mathjax")).init({
    loader: {
        load: ['input/tex', 'output/svg']
    },
});

const mathExpression = String.raw`\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}  
 2 & 0 & 1\\  
 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)`;

const renderedSvg = MathJax.startup.adaptor.innerHTML(
    MathJax.tex2svg(mathExpression)
);

fs.writeFileSync("test.svg", renderedSvg);
```

Here's how that TeX is supposed to look, as rendered by TeX and even by MathJax in HTML:

[image: correctly rendered expression]

Here's how it actually shows up in SVG:

[image: incorrectly rendered expression]

What's especially odd is that there is an almost imperceptible but definitely present amount of extra whitespace where the column line is supposed to be in the SVG, which means it's certainly doing *something*. But I don't quite know what and why the actual line does not render.

Here's the actual, raw SVG output: https://pastebin.com/raw/JXVefkft

Comment: @RobertLongson the SVG output is far too large to include directly but I edited the question to include a pastebin with the SVG output. It's not particularly easy to decipher to me and I don't know how possible it'll be to style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following styling information to the file

```
<style>
.mjx-solid {
  stroke-width: 80px;
}
</style>
```

makes the vertical line visible for me. You can make the stroke-width bigger or smaller to make the line more or less visible.

Comment: This does work! It's not a terribly general solution, but it did point me in the right direction of the general solution: MathJax has method called `MathJax.svgStylesheet()` that you can append to the SVG output to get everything to render correctly.